# Why does the javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder, fromUri() methods add an extra "/" at the end of hostname URI?

Tags: java, uri

I am trying to generate a redirect URI from the request for an OAuth2 authorization code flow. The request contains a hostname along with the scope and an authorization code. example:

```
redirect_uri=myapp2://oauth2redirect&scope=email+profile
```

So, the hostname here is : `myapp2://oauth2redirect`

Now, when I execute the below code to generate a redirect uri for the application it adds an extra "/" (slash) in the end instead of continuing with the query parameters i.e.:

```
myapp2://oauth2redirect/?code=abcdefghijkl
```

The extra/unwanted "/" in `myapp2://oauth2redirect/?` is making the redirection fail. 
Ideally it should be : `myapp2://oauth2redirect?code=abcdefghijkl&scope=`

```
public Response getResponse() {
    String uri = oAuthrequest.getRedirectURI();

    UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri(uri)
                        .queryParam("code", code);

    if (oAuthrequest.getState() != null) {
        uriBuilder.queryParam("state", oAuthrequest.getState());
    }

    if(scopeNames != null && scopeNames.size() > 0) {
        uriBuilder.queryParam("scope", StringUtil.toSingleString(scopeNames, " "));
    }

    logger.info("OAuth2 Authorization response success");

    return Response.status(302).cookie(cookies).location(uriBuilder.build()).build();
}
```

I think that the UriBuilder.fromUri(uri) method adds the extra "/" in the uri as I have debugged and checked the value of the String field "uri" is correct. But, once this line is executed it adds up the extra "/" after the uri and then proceeds by appending the query parameters.

Comment: Which UriBuilder are you using ?

Comment: @LeonardoPina it is Jersey's UriBuilder (javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder)

Comment: I believe the problem is within the URI: `myapp2://oauth2redirect&scope=email+profile`, since there is no `?` identifying parameters, the whole `oauth2redirect&scope=email+profile` is interpreted as the URI's authority

Comment: The String `uri = oAuthrequest.getRedirectURI();` method actually fetches the base url : `myapp2://oauth2redirect` and the scope is fetched up separetly. As I said, the data comes in correct but, when the code :     `UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri(uri).queryParam("code", code);` is executed the "/" comes in instead of "?" for the first query param in the url.

Comment: I think I got, check the answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I came up with a hacky solution: given that `getRedirectURI()` will return something like `"myapp2://oauth2redirect"`

```
// builds an URI object from the URI string
java.net.URI uri = java.net.URI.create(getRedirectURI());

// uses the authory(oauth2redirect) as the path to build the uri
UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromPath(
            // forcefully adds the double slashes (//), without this, 
            // at this point, the uri would be: myapp2:oauth2redirect
            "//" + uri.getAuthority())
            .scheme(uri.getScheme());

uriBuilder.queryParam("code", "myCode");

uriBuilder.build(); // produces the uri: myapp2://oauth2redirect?code=myCode
```

Comment: how about a test case where the uri ends with a "/" if the uri is = `myapp2://oauth2redirect/ `In this case it would remove the "/" at the end which is actually a part of the uri

Comment: the same answer would apply, you would just skip adding the parameter